# Mocking Javascript objects (specifically YUI)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock YUI for javascript testing. I want to mock a datatable, but im not sure how to do it.

Something like

```
 YAHOO.widget.DataTable = function(){

  };
```

so latter I could do something like

```
   assert.that(returnedDatatable, isOfType(YAHOO.widget.DataTable));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: js mockito or don't use YUI :)